# How can I select a class inside a div?

Tags: html, css

Hello i was wondering how you can target a class inside a DIV

heres a link to the code pen if you know how to fix it send a link back with the correct way

i am trying to target the ID Forms and the class selection

Code Pen Link: http://codepen.io/cmbaseball94/pen/HFpdx/

#### HTML

```
<div id="forms">


        <label>First Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"> <br />

        <label>Last Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"> <br />

        <label>Email:</label><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br />

        <label>Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required> <br />

        <label>Sex:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br>            
        <label>Favorite Characters:</label>
        <input id="selection" type="checkbox" name="character" value="Peter">Peter
        <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" class="selection">Lois
        <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" class="selection">Stewie
        <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" class="selection">Chris
        <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" class="selection">Meg<br>


        <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Write Something Here"></textarea><br>

         <label>Favorite Season:</label>
             <select id = "seasonlist">
               <option value = "1">One</option>
               <option value = "2">Two</option>
               <option value = "3">Three</option>
               <option value = "4">Four</option>
               <option value = "5">Five</option>
               <option value = "6">Six</option>
               <option value = "7">Seven</option>
               <option value = "8">Eight</option>
               <option value = "9">Nine</option>
               <option value = "10">Ten</option>
               <option value = "11">Eleven</option>
               <option value = "12">Twelve</option>
             </select> <br>

        <input type="submit"> 
        </div>
```

#### CSS

```
#forms {
    color: #FFF;
     width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

???? {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: have you read about `CSS selectors`? I think that is a must-read for everyone learning developing web.

Answer (score 1):

Since `selection` is the only class I see in your code, I would say this is how you do it:

**EDIT** Since you updated your answer and confirmed that you are trying to style the `selection` class, this is the way to do it. There are other ways to select that class depending on your specific markup, but in the most basic of situations, this is how it's done:

```
#forms .selection {
  color:black;
}
```

Comment: it was targeting the button not the text so i had to put a label tag before the text 

http://codepen.io/cmbaseball94/pen/HFpdx/

Heres the updated work

Comment: @user3461265 I'm sorry, I don't understand, is there a different issue now?

Comment: I'm afraid he didn't mean a class as we know it. He probably meant how to target an element within a form

Comment: @LOTUSMS I'm not so sure, he refers the the class `selection` in his post, and that is a class within his code... either way, I'm confused now lol

Comment: You noticed he uses selection as an id as well. That is enough to confuse anyone when using specificity, but it's the price of learning. He'll come around eventually when he starts mixing ids and classes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="forms">
        <form action="mailto:cmbaseball94@gmail.com" method="post">



      <span>First Name:</span><br />
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" /> <br />

      <span>Last Name:</span><br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"> <br />

      <span>Email:</span><br />
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br />

      <span>Password:</span><br />
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required /> <br />

        <span>Sex:</span>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" id="male"><label for="male">Male</label> 
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" id="female"><label for="female">Female</label> 
        <span>Favorite Characters:</span>
      <input id="selection" type="checkbox" name="character" value="Peter"/><label for="selection" class="selection">Peter</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" id="selection"/><label for="selection" class="selection">Lois</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" id="selection"/><label for="selection" class="selection">Stewie</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" id="selection"/><label for="selection" class="selection">Chris</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" name="character" value="Stewie" id="selection"/><label for="selection" class="selection">Meg</label> 
      <br />


      <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50" placeholder="Write Something Here"></textarea><br />

         <span>Favorite Season:</span>
             <select id = "seasonlist">
               <option value = "1">One</option>
               <option value = "2">Two</option>
               <option value = "3">Three</option>
               <option value = "4">Four</option>
               <option value = "5">Five</option>
               <option value = "6">Six</option>
               <option value = "7">Seven</option>
               <option value = "8">Eight</option>
               <option value = "9">Nine</option>
               <option value = "10">Ten</option>
               <option value = "11">Eleven</option>
               <option value = "12">Twelve</option>
             </select> <br />

  <input type="submit" /> 
        </div>
```

css

```
#forms {
    color: #000;
     width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.selection{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: it was targeting the button not the text so i had to put a label tag before the text 

http://codepen.io/cmbaseball94/pen/HFpdx/

Heres the updated work

Answer (score 0):

In that case you can simply use your div to map down to the element you are targetting. Since this is an input of type submit You can do this:

```
#forms input[type="submit"]{
     background-color:black;
     color:white;
}
```

[***DEMO HERE***](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Qy4/1/)